# Xamarin.Fomrs SQLite DateTime not inserted properly through Query

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I am generating queries at api side and I directly want to execute it in my local db.

I have a table like this.

```
[Table("TblUnit")]
public class TblUnit
{
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
    public int WebId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpeningStockDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add object using `InsertAsync(object)` method, object is inserted with proper date. But when I try to fire query, date is not added to database. After firing query when I try to fetch data from this table `OpeningStockDate` comes as `01/01/0001`.

```
//this is generated at api side and I directly want to fire query in my local sqlite db
var query = "insert into [TblUnit] (Name,Description,IsFavourite,WebId,CompanyId,OpeningStockDate) values('Bag','Description',true,12,185,'2021-03-04 10:00:00')";
```

I tried changing date format to `mm/dd/yyyy` as well. But no success.

I tried setting `storeDateTimeAsTicks` flag to false.

```
 static readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> lazyInitializer = new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() =>
    {
        return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags,false);
    });
```

But then my entire app starts behaving incorrect. I can not get data from this table. It shows datetime parsing exception. Also can not add data to the table using `InsertAsync` method.

What I am doing wrong here ? Please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead,you could try to store the dates as TEXT,like strings  ("YYYY-MM-DD").You could refer to [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: From api, I tried passing date like this `'u.OpeningStockDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")'`. Still getting same error.

Comment: Did you change the datatype to TEXT in your Sqlite ?

Comment: okay, got it. Working now. Thanks